# Path-based sticky session with Kubernetes

Tags: networking, load-balancing, sticky-session

I have a system on Kubernetes and I need path-based sticky session but couldn't find anything about it on the Internet.

**Scenario**

My system exposes 2 endpoints

```
/start
/<sessionid>/dosomething
```

When client hits to `/start`, a session id is returned. Client will then make requests to `/<sessionid>/dosomething`. This means the session id is dynamically generated.

I want to make sure all requests with the same session id in its path are always routed to the same backend (and keep in mind the **session ids are dynamically generated**).

**Note**
I prefer solutions that rely heavily on networking rather than on the application itself (I don't want the routing logic to be inside application code)